# Known publicly available modified UPX ELF packer

Tags: elf, packers, upx

Anyone know of any publicly available modified versions of UPX for ELF? I.e. one that is not able to be unpacked using `upx -d`. The unpacking stub in the binary is slightly obfuscated. I am looking to identify the source of these modifications.

Comment: Please give more details - I am not aware of such a list.

Comment: Jason, this had to do with reverse engineering because unpacking binaries and indentifiying the packer is reverse engineering.

Comment: but your question is just about a list (not unpacking or identifying), thus we can't contribute in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

UPX is already managing ELF (see: [UPX supported executable formats](http://upx.sourceforge.net/)). Or, did I miss the point of your question ?

But, note that UPX is not designed for obfuscation purpose, it mainly aims at compressing the executable.

Comment: I know it supports ELF. I have a binary that used a modified version of UPX in that the compression schemes, but that the unpacking stub is slightly obfuscated.

Comment: I better understand your question now. But, the best way to have an accurate answer would be to show the modification you found and/or part or the whole asm code of the packer prelude.